# Kineticjs alpha mask

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

With HTML5 `<canvas>` elements, it is possible to use one canvas to mask another.  For example, the following code will take the top canvas, use the alpha of the middle canvas and dump the result to the bottom canvas:

html:

```
<body style="background-color:#333;">
<img id="SourceImage" src="Src.png" style="display:none">
<img id="MaskImage" src="Mask.png" style="display:none">
<div><canvas id="cSrc"></canvas></div>
<div><canvas id="cMask"></canvas></div>
<div><canvas id="cDest"></canvas></div>
```

javascript:

```
var objSrc = document.getElementById('cSrc').getContext('2d');
var objMask = document.getElementById('cMask').getContext('2d');
var objDest = document.getElementById('cDest').getContext('2d');

objSrc.drawImage(document.getElementById("SourceImage"),0,0);
objMask.drawImage(document.getElementById("MaskImage"),0,0);

var imgs = objSrc.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 150);
var imga = objMask.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 150);
var pix = imgs.data;
var pixa = imga.data;

for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
    pix[i+3] = pixa[i+3];
}

objDest.putImageData(imgs, 0, 0);
```

Result:

[image: canvas mask result]

How would I go about doing the same thing in Kineticjs?  For instance, is there any way to to use one `Kinetic.Layer` as a mask for another `Kinetic.Layer` and then dump the results to a visible `Kinetic.Layer`?  I looked at the `clip(clip)` method, but it seems to be more for cutting rectangular holes in a canvas (possible for cropping?).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use offscreen html canvas(s) to do you alpha blending (as you've done above).

Then use your #objDest as the source for a Kinetic.Image.

```
var image1=new Kinetic.Image({
    image:objDest,
    ...
});
```

Comment: This would work for 2x Canvas elements as shown above, but I am more interested in using one `Kinetic.Layer` to mask another `Kinetic.Layer` so that the masking gets refreshed on each successive draw.  One way I considered doing it was by having 3x Kineticjs.Stage objects two of which are hidden ... but even still, is there a way to trigger a draw of Stage3 after Stage1 & 2 are finished?  Possibly a callback on the .draw() or .BatchDraw() functions?

Comment: Never-mind, I just realized what I was asking for could be accomplished simply by calling Stage1.Draw(); Stage2.Draw(); MaskIt(); putMaskonStage3(); Stage3.Draw();